# Kali-Linux installed- sharing partitions with Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, multi-boot, kali-linux

So I followed the instructions to install Kali-Linux with a manual install. It appears I can see all of my files in my Windows 10 OS, even though I thought I selected separate partitions on my HDD and SSD to install Kali.

What to do?...

I'm just alarmed at the fact that it appears my partitions are being shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most Linux distributions include all the filesystem modules, it is normal to be able to see NTFS partitions.

You will need to run one of the commands below and check how many partitions you have on the system.

```
sudo lsblk
```

OR

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

The output should give you the answers you are seeking.

Comment: Cool. I have an OS and data partition for my Linux system, is there a way I can explore the data partition?

Comment: @KieranOjakangas you have to check what kind of filesystem they are on. That will tell you if it's ext or NTFS. You can mount whatever filesystem you want to a directory in Linux and explore it freely.